# Literal asterisk in the beginning of the line in asciidoc to html conversion

Tags: html, escaping, literals, asciidoc

AsciiDoc source like `a * a` is converted to HTML as normal text "a * a". If the asterisk is the first non-space character in the line, it starts a list (this is normal). However, I need to start a paragraph with literal asterisk. I tried the following to escape it:

- `` `*` ``

  - `*` (rendered inside `<code>`)
- `\*`

  - \* (rendered as normal text but with backslash present)
- `+*+`

  - `*` (rendered inside `<code>`)
- `pass::[*]`

  - error: `block macro cannot occur here: pass::[*]`
- `'*'`

  - *** (rendered inside `<em>` — the closest to what I need so far)

How to specify an asterisk in the beginning of the line in AsciiDoc source so that it appears as normal text in the HTML output?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It turned out that for [inline passthroughs](http://asciidoc.org/userguide.html#X77) a different form of `pass` is required. I also checked the solution suggested by [@Mario Lopez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40998917/3476320). I summarize the options below:

- passthrough:

  - `pass:[*]`
  - `+++*+++`
  - `$$*$$`
- disturb list pattern

  - `{empty}*` ("official" solution from [FAQ](http://asciidoc.org/faq.html#_how_can_i_escape_a_list))
  - `*text`
  - `*{sp}`
- HTML escapes

  - `&#42;`
  - `&#x002A;`

Answer (score 5):

You have two options that I know of. The pattern that converts it to a list is specifically an asterisk followed by a space.

```
* item
```

Which will get rendered like this:

- item

You could either omit the space or use the space attribute.

```
*item
*{sp}item
```

Which will get rendered like this (respectively):

*item
* item

More information about attributes and substitutions can be found here:
http://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoc-syntax-quick-reference/#attributes-and-substitutions